# getting list index out of range when extracting dataframe rows conditionally

Tags: python, pandas

Extracting part of the tokens data frame throws up list index out of range error.

**Edited to show full code**

```
tokens['len'] = tokens['token_raw'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
txt = "this is a sample text"
input_df = pd.DataFrame(txt.lower().split(), columns=['input_text'])
input_df = input_df['input_text'].apply(lambda x: flag_nonword(x))

def flag_nonword(w):
    input_len = len(w)+3
    tokens_ext = tokens.loc[tokens['len'] < input_len ]
    tokens_ext.sort_values('len',ascending=True, inplace = True)
    tokens_ext['ed'] = tokens_ext['token_raw'].apply(lambda x: 
nltk.edit_distance(w,x))
    tokens_ext.sort_values(by=['ed', 'freq'], ascending=[True, False])
    return list(tokens_ext.iloc[:6,0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or two `iloc`s:

```
def flag_nonword(w):
    input_len = len(w)+3
    tokens_ext = tokens.loc[tokens['len'] < input_len] 
    return list(tokens.iloc[:,0].iloc[:6])
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try?

```
def flag_nonword(w):
    input_len = len(w)+3
    tokens_ext = tokens.loc[tokens['len'] < input_len + 1]
    tokens_ext.sort_values('len',ascending=True, inplace = True)
    tokens_ext['ed'] = tokens_ext['token_raw'].apply(lambda x:
```